# function in angular for validating a field in database is not properly running

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi so I tried to validate if there a user has already participated in an event so this are my codes for angular.

html

```
  <form>
        <span style="display:none">
          <input ng-model="userInfo.user_id">
          <input ng-model="charity[0].charity_id">
          <input ng-model="CurrProjects[0].project_id">      
        </span> 
            <button type="submit"class="button button-full button-outline button-assertive" ng-click="check()">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-star"></i> I want to volunteer for this! <i class="icon ion-ios-star"></i>
            </button>
        </a>
        </form>
```

for example the value of user_id is 1 , same as for the charity_id and project_id

here is the function for my controller which i think is the problem

```
    $scope.userVolunteer ={};
    $scope.check = function(){volunteer.checkVol($scope.userInfo.user_id,$scope.charity[0].charity_id,
                    $scope.CurrProjects[0].project_id);
    setTimeout( function(){
        $scope.checker = volunteer.checkResult();
        $scope.$apply();
                 }, 100);

     console.log($scope.checker);

        if($scope.checker != null){
            $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'You are already registered to this event'
                 });
           }
        else if($scope.checker != []){
            $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'You are already registered to this event'
                 });
           } 
        else{
            console.log("good");
            $state.go('app.volunteer');

        }               
    }
```

and the volunteer service

```
function checkResult(){
    return userVolStatus;
}
function  checkVol(user, charity, proj){
        if(user || charity || proj) {
            var userData = {
            userId : user,
            charId : charity,
            projId : proj
                }
                $http(
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        header: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        url: 'http://localhost/folder/controller/function',
                        data: userData
                    }
                )
                .then(
                    function success( response ) {
                         userVolStatus = response.data;
                         console.log(response.data);
                    },
                    function error( response ) {
                         userVolStatus = response.data;
                        console.log(response.data);
                        // handle error
                    }

                );
            }
            else{

            }
        return userVolStatus;
```

}

what happens is when there is no data in the database, it prompts with "you are already registered to this event!". what could be the problem with this? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
($scope.checker !== null)
```

and

```
($scope.checker.length !== 0)
```